# Is it possible to redirect a Wix page to an external URL without waiting for the page to fully load?

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I'm using the wix-location module to redirect a Wix website page to an external page:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 

$w.onReady(function () {
     wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
})
```

This waits for the page to load fully and then does a redirection. Is there a way to redirect without waiting for the whole page to load? Or alternatives to wixLocation.to()?

It isn't a huge deal in my case because ended up clearing the entire Wix page of text/images so that it isn't very obvious that the page loaded and then redirected; however, it would be nice if the redirection was faster and I was wondering if there's any other way to do so.

Comment: @Sean just tried that! but unfortunately I don't think it changed anything...still loads all of the page first

Answer (score 1):

use `wixLocation.to()` right at the top.

or

go to page setting and set redirection.

`wixLocation.to()` doesn't have to wait for the page contents to be ready, which obviously you intend to avoid.

```js
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 

wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
//$w.onReady(function () {
//   
//})
```